# Insert a new document, populate and validate it

Tags: validation, mongoose

I've managed to get this working, but it seems very inefficient:

```
//card schema
new Schema({
    name: String,
    type: String,
    setname: String,
    text: String,
    image: String,
    faction: String,
    color: String,
    rarity: String,
    limit: Number,
    number: Number,
    endurance: Number,
    level: Number,
    pur: Number,
    stages: Array
});

//deck schema
new Schema({
    personality: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card'}],
    mastery: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card'}],
    main: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Card'}],
    owner: String
});

//example deck model validator
Model.schema.path('mastery').validate(function(value) {
    if (!value || (typeof value == 'Array' && !value.length)) {return false;}
    return value[0].type == 'Mastery';
}, 'Mastery card is not of type mastery');

server.prototype.addDeck = function(client, ids) {
Deck.collection.insert({
    owner: client.conn.uid,
    main: ids.main,
    personality: ids.personality,
    mastery: ids.mastery
}, function(err, res1) {
    Deck.findById(res1[0]._id).populate('main personality mastery').exec(function(err, res2) {
        res2.save(function(err, res3) {
            if (err) {
                //fail
            } else {
                //success
            }
        });
    });
});
}
```

First I create a new doc, bypassing validation so I can then populate it and attempt to save it so it can be validated. Some of the validation methods check values on a card such as it's color, which is why it is necessary to populate it. There are 4 separate queries just to create it, possibly 5 if validation fails. Is there some way of making this more efficient?

Comment: Why don't you put your validation logic **before** making queries to the database?

Comment: How is that possible with Mongoose?